# What css should I add to fix the following jquery datatable overlap?

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js, datatables

I am trying to implement the following table in my website : [Datatable with knockout example](http://datatables.net/dev/knockout/).

My website is divided in to2 main `divs`, the left side and the right one. It seems to work right, but my CSS isn't quite good. Here is what happens : 
[PrintScreen](http://prntscr.com/9c3794).

I've taken the CSS from the example website, also tried to change the width of the `demo` div or the table itself but it doesn't seem to do the trick. The table resizes but the features around it don't change their position.

Here are some direct links to the css: [jquery datatables css](http://datatables.net/dev/knockout/css/jquery.dataTables.css) / [page css](http://datatables.net/dev/knockout/css/demo_page.css)

Didn't get exactly the same result in Jsfiddle but it is similar : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqkbg9ht/)

Comment: i find it hard to debug an...image!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @A.Wolff Added links to the css. Trying to reproduce in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `file-left` and `file-right` elements have 40% and 60% of the available width, but the `container` inside `file-left` has a width of 800px and since `file-left` also has `overflow: hidden` most of the `container` is hidden / cut off.

Removing the fixed width from the `container` leads to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqkbg9ht/1/) where the table is small but complete:

[image]

PS: `file-left` was inside of `file-right`, I changed that too.